# How to know whether the keyboard appearing is Split or normal?

Tags: ios, ipad

In my iPad app, I am posting keyboard notification that will bring the popover to a certain height above the keyboard. This works fine with the normal keyboard. But then in iOS 5, if the user selects Split keyboard, the popover will behave incorrectly. How can I know whether the user has selected the split keyboard, so that I can arrange the popover height according to the keyboard presented?

Comment: Solved! No notification will be sent when the keyboard is split.

Comment: hi ganesh, I have the same problem with keyboard.I am arranging my view's according to whether keyboard visible or not. Becaue of the split key board even when I open the key board I am not getting any notification.how did you solved this? could you please share me the same.

Comment: Hi Chaithanya Kiran, You need not re-arrange the views when the keyboard is split, coz, the split keyboard appears at the sides and they take very less screen space, if it really hides, then its a matter to think :(

Comment: hi ganesh, My question is how do we know that the keyboard is split.becoz in ios 5.1 when we split the keyboard it is not giving any notificaiton or it is not calling any delegate method. So how to identify the splitting of keyboard to rearrage our views?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is not to overthink this. Nothing of any importance has changed. If the keyboard comes into docked position at the bottom of the screen, you will get a "show" notification. If it leaves the docked position at the bottom of the screen, you will get a "hide" notification. That's exactly what happened before iOS 5.

The only difference is that instead of leaving the docked position because it is moving offscreen, it might be leaving the docked position because the user undocked it. You'll still get a "hide", so you can move your interface back into its base position. You don't need to know that the keyboard is now undocked (though you can find out that it is not offscreen from UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification if you really want to). The reason you don't need to know is that when the keyboard is undocked / split, the user can be proactive and move the keyboard if it's in the way of something that needs to be seen.

Thus, all your old code from before iOS 5 continues to work just fine. It's all really quite clever.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Thank you for the reply. But i have a problem.Whenever keyboard is visible/hiding i am arranging my UITextField position over the key board. but in a particular situation like when keyboard is visible now I have moved my text field up. in this case if user splits the key board and closes the key board, my text field is still at the top because I am not getting keyboardwillhide notification. what to do in this situation?

Comment: Hi chaithanya kiran T, When the user switches from normal to Split Keyboard, KeyboardWillHide notification gets called. Here you can re-arrange the frame for the TextField.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, your are rite, but it is till iOS 5.0. I have upgraded my iPAD to iOS 5.1 in which when we split the keyboard it is not calling KeyboardWillHide notification.Apple made the split key board handling more complicated :( :( :(

Comment: While user can choose to move/switch the kb if it is in the way, it is a nightmare for enterprise app developers and IT support personnel.